# Generating Flask boilerplate from OpenAPI doc

Tags: flask, openapi

I am planning to create a suite of REST API services with Flask, starting from scratch. I want to use this opportunity to create an OpenAPI-compliant project.

I just recently read the OpenAPI specs and I think I understood its philosophy, which is writing the doc first, and then the software implementation. I think this is a wonderful approach for separating planning and coding.

However, a quick web search on "generate flask boilerplate from openapi doc" only shows how to generate OpenAPI docs from existing Flask code. I understand the practical need to adapt existing projects to OpenAPI, but I would also expect to find tools that do the opposite, which I believe is the "right" way in OpenAPI's concept.

The only tool that seems to do this is the Swagger CodeGen, but I don't think that works for Python/Flask.

My questions:

1. Are there any tools to generate Flask boilerplate code from an OpenAPI spec? (best if from YAML)
2. Am I understanding this right? The absence of tools to do this raises a red flag for me.